# Copy ID3 tags _or_ audio between MP3 files

Tags: terminal, audio, mp3, id3-tag

I had the **W**rong audio in an MP3 file (**W**) in Music.app with the correct tags but.  I opened that, and a file (**C**) with the **C**orrect audio, with [Amadeus Pro](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/amadeus-pro/id438292371?mt=12).  I copied the good audio and pasted it in place of the wrong one.

How could this be automated in zsh?  Either transfer audio from C to W without changing tags, or transfer tags from W to C, then overwrite W (`mv C W`).

- `exiftool` can't write to MP3 files
- `eyeD3` can both read and write, but I don't see a simple way for it to
  transfer all tags
- I don't know whether `id3v2` can do it, but it is unacceptable
  because it trashes multi-byte UTF8 characters
- A few different web searches turned up nothing helpful.
- SE's "similar questions" didn't help either.

Comment: Can‘t you just use eyeD3 to read each tag in a loop and apply it to the target?

Comment: Probably.  I actually did something for several tags.  But it would be convenient to do them all in one command.  exiftool can do it for image files but not MP3.  Also, the tag name in the output of reading is different from the name to use for writing.  So I'd have to redirect to a temp file and then do substitutions to convert the temp file into a script to do the writes.